# Looking for a way to add data to bean validation exception

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have a custom bean validator which implements `boolean isValid(Object, ConstraintValidatorContext)` which performs some business logic and returns true/false depending on that logic.

What I would like to be able to do is add some data to the ConstraintViolation exception which is thrown. Any exception handlers which catch and process it can then tease out this extra data which would include more details about the error/arg that caused it. Right now I can only associate a message with the violation which lacks these dynamic details.

For example, the object passed into isValid contains a map whose contents are validated by the validator. Because the validator API only returns a boolean I lose the granularity of what member(s) of the map triggered the constraint violation. I am looking for some way of being able to preserve and pass this information forward.

**EDIT 8/13/2013 - Example solution involving JAX-RS**

(leaves out some JAXB details not relevant to this question)

**FooParam.java**

```
public class FooParam {
  private Map<String, String> subParamMap;

  public Map<String, String> getSubParamMap() { return this.subParamMap; }
  public void setSubParamMap(Map<String, String> subParamMap) {
    this.subParamMap = subParamMap;
  }

  public FooParam() { this.subParamMap = new HashMap<>(); }
}
```

**FooResource.java**

```
public class FooResource {

  ...

  public void doSomething(@CheckValidParam(value=FooResoure.class) FooParam fooParam) { 
    ...
  }
}
```

**CheckValidParam.java**

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckValidParamValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CheckValidParam{

    String message() default "{com.foo.bar.CheckValidParam.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default  { };

    Class<?> value();

    @Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        CheckValidParam[] value();
    }
}
```

**CheckValidParamValidator.java**

```
public class CheckValidParamValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckValidParam, FooParam> {

    private Class<?> entityClass;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CheckValidParam checkValidParam ) {
        this.entityClass = checkValidParam.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(FooParam fooParam, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

        String message = constraintValidatorContext.getDefaultConstraintMessageTemplate();
        constraintValidatorContext.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
        boolean isValid = true;
        Map<String, String> subParamMap = fooParam.getSubParamMap();

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : subParamMap.entrySet()) {
          //Contrived validation logic
          if (entry.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("junk")) {   
            constraintValidatorContext.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(message)
                                      .addNode(entry.getKey()).addConstraintViolation();
            isValid = false;
           }
        }
        return isValid;
    }
}
```

Stripped down version of the class which intercepts MethodConstraintViolationExceptions thrown in the JAX-RS pipeline to illustrate pulling out the invalid params and associated error message.

**MethodConstraintValidationMapper.java**

```
@Provider
public class MethodConstraintValidationMapperimplements ExceptionMapper<MethodConstraintViolationException> {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MethodConstraintValidationMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MethodConstraintViolationException ex) {
        Response response;
        Set<MethodConstraintViolation<?>> violations = ex.getConstraintViolations();
        List<ValidationExceptionError> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (MethodConstraintViolation<?> methodConstraintViolation : ex.getConstraintViolations()) {
            ValidationExceptionError error = new ValidationExceptionError();
            error.setFieldName(((PathImpl) methodConstraintViolation.getPropertyPath()).getLeafNode().asString());
            error.setErrorMessage(methodConstraintViolation.getMessage());
            errors.add(error);
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).entity(new GenericEntity<List<ValidationExceptionError>>(errors) {}).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Would like some feedback for the down votes so that I can improve this question, thanks.

Comment: @leppie re: the java tag. java is impled. If you click on bean-validation you will see quit a few other questions without the explicit java tag and they are all java. Ironic too that you seem to be a C# person.

Comment: I dont see your point. They should all be tagged with Java. And no, no tag is ever implied, even if you think so.

Comment: May I know how can you map the CheckValidParamValidator  to MethodConstraintViolationException specifically? Can you answer my question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275630/mapping-specific-constraint-validator-to-specific-contraintviolationexception-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve detailed information about the invalid value from the [ConstraintViolation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/validation/ConstraintViolation.html) object. In particular `getPropertyPath()` should be helpful for you, as it allows to navigate the path to the leaf node and provides access to the concerned key (in case a value in a map is validated) via `Node#getKey()`.

Comment: Thanks, that was a helpful! That got me down the path of adding nodes to the ConstraintValidatorContext for each invalid map entry. Then I pulled them out of the ConstraintViolation object as you suggested. Works like a charm.

Comment: @Gunnar can you answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20275630/mapping-specific-constraint-validator-to-specific-contraintviolationexception-in