# Mapping specific constraint validator to specific ContraintViolationException in Jersey

Tags: java, hibernate, jax-rs, bean-validation, jersey-2.0

I am trying to create a custom validator and mapped it into a specific constraintViolationException. The reason is I want to create different custom exception for different constraint. For example, if a user is not found in the database, a not found violationException is triggered, while if the user has invalid username, a bad response violationException will be executed instead.

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD })
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserNotValidValidator.class)
public @interface UserIsValid { ... }
```

mapped into

```
public class ConstraintExceptionMapper implements
    ExceptionMapper<ConstraintViolationException> {
   public Response toResponse(ConstraintViolationException e) { ... }
}
```

To be more specific, the question is whether bean hibernate validator supports multiple constraint exception mapper.

Comment: Came across something similar here https://github.com/42BV/jarb/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception mappers are a concept of JAX-RS not of Bean Validation. You should create one exception mapper for `ConstraintViolationException` and have it create different responses based on the violations contained within a given violation exception. E.g. you can examine the violated constraint type via `ConstraintViolation.getConstraintDescriptor().getAnnotation().annotationType().

Comment: but isn't it hard to maintain the code if there are too many (if cases) annotation type in `ConstraintViolationException ?

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion / example of how to handle the constraint mapping exception. I will need a for loop to check the annotationType() and for some cases I will want to throw a badrequestexception before notfoundexception, which are not a clean solution.

Comment: I am looking and wondering if there are some annotations that can mapped the specific custom constraint to a specific custom mapper.

Comment: You could define a meta-annotation which you use to tag the different categories of your custom constraints. You then retrieve the annotation type of violated constraints as described above and retrieve the category by reading the meta-annotation; depending on the category you could then create a specific response.